# Jetpack Compose, convert XML to JetPack Compose

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I wanted to convert the XML code to Jetpack Compose code using the Recompose plugin (https://github.com/pocmo/recompose).

The following error occurs when trying to install a plug-in: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgjJD.png)

My version of Android Studio: [About Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayvh5.png)

Please help.

Comment: See the existing issue: https://github.com/pocmo/recompose/issues/114

Answer (score 0):

It looks like recompose has not been updated to run as a plugin in the later Android Studio versions. You can still run recompose from the command line. My experience was that it was limited and could not handle a large amount of my layout XML, as I have a good bit of logic around animations, layer-lists, themed vector assets, dynamically updated texts and drawables, and conditional visibility.

To try with the command line, you can use something like this

```
./gradlew recompose-cli:run --args="C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\SmarterGarage\sglibrary\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml"
```